# Why is the C# stack based on a dynamic array?

Tags: .net, stack

I looked at msdn and saw that .net stack has an internal array and when it's capacity is full it grows the array (like dynamic array). As we always pop the head from the stack, isn't Linked List more efficient for stack implementation?